# VMWare: Ubuntu stuck on boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, vmware, reboot

**Setup:**

- VMWare version 15.5
- Host OS: Windows 10 Home Edition
- Quest OS: Ubuntu 18.04

**Issue:**

Issue started after problem in login screen. I tried to login but every time I entered password and hit "Enter", it just went back to "Select User" -point without any error.
So I restarted the machine and then it got stuck in the boot. Only think that happens is text blinking.

[image: Ubuntu stuck at this point]

I have other VMs installed on the PC and they work fine.
I checked the log files and there are 2 lines that repeats until I shutdown from VMWare.

```
vmware.log( part of it)

...
2019-09-25T22:21:25.613+03:00| vmx| I125: TOOLS Setting toolsVersionStatus = TOOLS_STATUS_UNMANAGED
2019-09-25T22:21:25.613+03:00| vmx| I125: Tools_SetVersionAndType did nothing; new tools version (10346) and type (4) match old Tools version and type
2019-09-25T22:21:25.834+03:00| vcpu-1| I125: SOUND 866.712130 ES1371Win32GetMixerCtl mixerGetLineInfo error 1024
2019-09-25T22:21:26.065+03:00| vmx| I125: TOOLS state change 3 returned status 1
2019-09-25T22:21:26.065+03:00| vmx| I125: Vix: [mainDispatch.c:4150]: VMAutomationReportPowerStateChange: Reporting power state change (opcode=2, err=0).
2019-09-25T22:21:26.065+03:00| vmx| I125: Tools: Changing running status: 2 => 1.
2019-09-25T22:21:26.065+03:00| vmx| I125: Tools: [RunningStatus] Last heartbeat value 2 (last received 0s ago)
2019-09-25T22:21:26.578+03:00| vcpu-0| I125: Guest: Mesa: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
2019-09-25T22:21:26.578+03:00| vcpu-0| I125: Guest: Mesa: 19.0.8
2019-09-25T22:21:26.617+03:00| vcpu-0| I125: Guest: Mesa: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
2019-09-25T22:21:26.618+03:00| vcpu-0| I125: Guest: Mesa: 19.0.8
2019-09-25T22:21:26.899+03:00| vcpu-2| I125: Guest: Mesa: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
2019-09-25T22:21:26.899+03:00| vcpu-2| I125: Guest: Mesa: 19.0.8
2019-09-25T22:21:26.917+03:00| vcpu-2| I125: Guest: Mesa: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
2019-09-25T22:21:26.917+03:00| vcpu-2| I125: Guest: Mesa: 19.0.8
2019-09-25T22:21:27.095+03:00| vcpu-1| I125: Guest: Mesa: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
2019-09-25T22:21:27.095+03:00| vcpu-1| I125: Guest: Mesa: 19.0.8
2019-09-25T22:21:27.104+03:00| vcpu-1| I125: Guest: Mesa: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
2019-09-25T22:21:27.105+03:00| vcpu-1| I125: Guest: Mesa: 19.0.8
2019-09-25T22:21:27.279+03:00| vcpu-2| I125: Guest: Mesa: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
2019-09-25T22:21:27.279+03:00| vcpu-2| I125: Guest: Mesa: 19.0.8
2019-09-25T22:21:27.291+03:00| vcpu-2| I125: Guest: Mesa: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
2019-09-25T22:21:27.291+03:00| vcpu-2| I125: Guest: Mesa: 19.0.8
2019-09-25T22:21:27.478+03:00| vcpu-0| I125: Guest: Mesa: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
2019-09-25T22:21:27.478+03:00| vcpu-0| I125: Guest: Mesa: 19.0.8
2019-09-25T22:21:27.489+03:00| vcpu-0| I125: Guest: Mesa: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
2019-09-25T22:21:27.489+03:00| vcpu-0| I125: Guest: Mesa: 19.0.8
2019-09-25T22:21:27.629+03:00| vcpu-3| I125: Guest: Mesa: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
2019-09-25T22:21:27.629+03:00| vcpu-3| I125: Guest: Mesa: 19.0.8
2019-09-25T22:21:27.638+03:00| vcpu-3| I125: Guest: Mesa: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
2019-09-25T22:21:27.639+03:00| vcpu-3| I125: Guest: Mesa: 19.0.8
...
```

**What I tried:**

- Editing VMWare settings:

  - CPU count to 1
  - Setting network and sound card not connect automatically
  - Display -> Accelerate 3D Graphics to false
  - Update VMWare to newest version (15.5)
- In Grub:

  - Edit launch option to use nomodeset
  - Recovery option ( everything on the list )

If more information is needed, I'll update the question.

**Question:**
Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Is your Ubuntu Guest 64-bit (likely) and so do you have BIOS VT-D enabled for 64-bit virtualization?  Do you have a backup of the system?

Comment: @John It is 64-bit and I think so since it worked before and other VMs are still working. And I don't have a recent backup, but I can use live CD to access the virtual drive if needed.

Comment: I cannot see anything in all the errors that points to a cause of it not booting. Make a new Ubuntu guest, set it up, make sure it boots, and then copy your apps and data from the first machine.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue. Ubuntu stopped booting after the same output line. For me, the VM ran out of disk space. 2 Options worked out to get it running again:

- Start Ubuntu in recovery mode by presing shift right after 'VM Ware' shows up and select 'clean' to free some space.
- Edit your VM while shut down and provision some additional diskspace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it takes a bit long to load. What I can see on your pictures doesn't look like errors, it just the startup procedure of ubuntu. If it takes to long, maybe reinstall it and check if the same problem appears again

Comment: I let it run for 15 minutes before shutdown but I will try to let in run longer. And that does look like normal except that the VMWare log is filled with hundreds of rows of this( Longer I let it run, more rows there are ):
xx: Guest: Mesa: SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
xx :Guest: Mesa: 19.0.8
But I don't know what it is trying to do, since I haven't found any information online.
And I have another VM ( Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit ) that do work.

Answer (score 0):

The disk might be full. Try to free up the disk space manually. One option that worked for me was

- enter GRUB (press esc when the VM boots up)
- select Advanced options for Ubuntu
- enter root
- use the following command to search for big ticket files that **you are comfortable deleting**

`du -sh /* | sort -h`

- then you can delete the files you think aren't useful by using
  `rm -rf <file_name>`.

The `du` command above may not include hidden files so you can search for those using the following:
`du -sh .[^.]*`